# How to do substring with variable length in a for loop inside batch files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, substring

I am trying to do some string comparison and extraction in a batch file. The operation takes place on a set of folder names from a SVN repository.

```
for /f %%f in ('svn list https://dev_server/svn/product/branches') do ( 
    set folder=%%f 

    echo Folder: %folder%

    :: get substring from %folder% starting at 0 with a length of %length%
    :: if this substring is equal to %folderStart% then get substring from %folder% starting at position %length%   
)
```

There are a couple of problems here:

1. The value of %%f is not assigned to %folder% for some reason.
2. Even though I have searched the web extensively, I didn't find a solution to doing substring with variable length. The batch file substring function :~ only seems to take fixed integer values.

Does anyone have an idea how I could implement the functions in the commented section in the code above?

Answer (score 7):

Dynamic substring is easy with delayed expansion.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "string=1234567890"

::using a normal variable
set len=5
echo !string:~0,%len%!

::using a FOR variable
for /l %%n in (1 1 10) do echo !string:~0,%%n!
```

It can also work with search and replace

Comment: Yes, that's how I SHOULD of done it, if I hadn't wandered off down the wrong path.

Comment: Doesn't that leading 0 make it octal? in your !string:~0%len%! (see http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_leadingzero.php)

Comment: @Abacus - Not if I have the correct code! There is supposed to be a comma between `0` and `%len%`. I've edited the answer with the correction. Thanks for finding and reporting the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
echo %folder%
```

needs to be

```
echo !folder!
```

Hopefully the following shows hows to do the substring

```
@echo off
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    set theString=abcd

    for %%f in (1 2 3 4) do ( 

        set pos=%%f

        call :Resolve theString:~0,!pos!

        echo !retval!

    )

goto :eof

:Resolve

  for  %%a in ("^!%*^!") do set retval=%%~a

goto :eof
```

which gives

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
```