# Use a variable on SET in Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I´m trying to use a variable instead of a fixed number here:

```
set PACK_VERSION=Testing12345
set PACK_VERSION=%PACK_VERSION:~7,100%
echo %PACK_VERSION%
```

Instead of this number 7, I would like to use a variable, something like this:

```
set VARNUM=7
set PACK_VERSION=Testing12345
set PACK_VERSION=%PACK_VERSION:~%VARNUM%,100%
echo %PACK_VERSION%
```

I don´t know how to insert that properly, anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch files: How to do substring with variable length in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913453/batch-files-how-to-do-substring-with-variable-length-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "usual" way is using [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set VARNUM=7
set PACK_VERSION=Testing12345
set PACK_VERSION=!PACK_VERSION:~%VARNUM%!
echo %PACK_VERSION%
```

but there is also a little trick to do it without delayed expansion (you have to parse the line twice, `call` is a good method to do so):

```
set VARNUM=7
set PACK_VERSION=Testing12345
call set PACK_VERSION=%%PACK_VERSION:~%VARNUM%%%
echo %PACK_VERSION%
```