# How to echo a single digit from a string variable depending on another variable in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to echo a single digit from a string assigned to a variable, but the position of the echoed digit would be determined by another variable.
Something like:

```
set a=ABCDEF
set b=3
echo %a:~%b%,1%
```

As if you wanted to echo the 3rd digit in the `ABCDEF` string this would be the same as:

```
echo %a:~3,1%
```

The reason im trying to do it this way is because the b variable will be prompted from the user several times with different values.

Comment: It's "Dynamic substring".

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913453/)

Comment: Sure thing. Please edit your post better next time, make use those buttons on the editor. For example the `{}` button can easily format your code block.

Comment: Your statement is absolutely incorrect. If you want to echo the 3rd digit, you'd use `echo %a:~2,1%`. This of course means that if the content of `%b%` is being entered by the end user, for instance, you'd need to use `set /a` to deduct `1` from it first. As for your question problem you have two choices, either enable delayed expansion and use, `echo !a:~%b%,1!`, or use a call statement like this, `call echo %%a:~%b%,1%%`.

Comment: This type of management is described at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990), although the topic is different...

Answer (score 1):

An example showing both methods:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "str=VALUE"
Echo Your string is %str%

Choice /C 12345 /M "Choose a positional digit"
Set /A int=%ERRORLEVEL%-1
Call Echo Your positional digit matches the character %%str:~%int%,1%%

Timeout 2 /NoBreak >Nul

Choice /C 12345 /M "Choose a positional digit"
Set /A int=%ERRORLEVEL%-1
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Echo Your positional digit matches the character !str:~%int%,1!
EndLocal

Timeout -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to `enabledelayedexpansion`

see `set /?` and `setlocal /?` from cmd console.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set a=ABCDEF
set b=3
echo !a:~%b%,1!
```

Also, take not that effectively we start counting at 0, so `b=3` would result in `echo`ing `D`